# User Controls and JavaScript and Master Pages

Tags: asp.net

Consider the following situation:

There is a master page with a contentPlaceHolder for all javascript...

for speed issuses this section is at the bottom of the page.

my user control generates some javascript that make use of some references in the master page javascript (Jquery library)

so, if my user control is rendered before the master page javascript, it won't work.

and this is my question:

how do I make some javascript code block inside my .ascx file to be rendered to the asp:Content JavaScript in the .aspx page

or maybe my all thinking is worng?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the javascript in ascx is also required by master page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works for you:

Where in the "bottom" of the Master Page? If you move it **inside the closing server-side form control** and use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` in your user control, it will inject that script of your control "before the closing `<form/>` tag" (which will be ***after*** your your static script call).

Master Page - right **above** the closing server-side ASP.Net `</form>`:

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js "></script>
</form>
```

Content Page (nothing special):

```
<%@ Register src= ....

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <uc1:jscript_inject ID="jscript_inject1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

User Control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "foo", @"alert('foo');", true);

}
```

This is how its rendered (HTML view source in browser):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js "></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    alert('foo');//]]>
</script>
....
</form>
```

As advertised, `alert('foo');` is below the "pre-defined" jq cdn call....

Comment: how is it possible to Register Startup Script from the .ascx file? it is not very easy to handle big scripts via code behind

Answer (score 0):

Cheers useful.
Interestingly this works for `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` but not `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude`, and instead the 'include' gets added to the top of the form.